# Knowing if a python cached property has been accessed without actually accessing it

Tags: python, python-descriptors

There are many examples out there of method decorators that will transform a method into a cached property. Sometimes though, I'd like to check if the cache is "active", meaning that the attribute was accessed and the cache was filled.

For example, if I'm using a `rows` cached to store an sql table in a `rows`, I'd like to compute the length of my table based on the cache, if it's been filled, but through a separate sql call if not. How do I check if `rows` has been accessed without triggering its access?

Here's a nice decorator taken from  David Beazley's "Python Cookbook") I'm using for my cached property needs. I've enhanced it to enable my current hack.

```py
class lazyprop:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            value = self.func(instance)
            setattr(instance, self.func.__name__, value)
            setattr(instance, self.func.__name__ + '__cache_active', True)  # my hack
            return value
```

Example of use:

```py
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...     @lazyprop
...     def len(self):
...         print('generating "len"')
...         return len(self.a)
>>> t = Test([0, 1, 2])
>>> # See what happens if I ask if there is a 'len' attribute:
>>> hasattr(t, 'len')
generating "len"
3
>>> t.len
5
```

So the `hasattr` actually triggers the `len` method call, so I can't use that. Anyway, I wouldn't want to use it because I'm not asking for the existence of an attribute (the key/reference), but the existence of (i.e. prior computation of) it's value.

Given the line marked by 'my hack', I can now do this:

```py
def has_active_cache(instance, attr):
    return getattr(instance, attr + '__cache_active', False)
```

```py
>>> t = Test([0, 1, 2])
>>> print("Accessed:", has_active_cache(t, 'len'))
Accessed: False
>>> t.len
generating "len"
3
>>> print("Accessed:", has_active_cache(t, 'len'))
Accessed: True
```

But I believe there's a more graceful solution than this. Perhaps one that would come "coupled" with the `lazyprop` itself...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as an FYI, property caching is a part of the Python 3.8 standard library through `functools`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=s#functools.cached_property

using this decorator, you can access the `__dict__` attribute of your class directly to check if the value is cached.

Using the example from the documentation...

```
import statistics
from functools import cached_property


class DataSet:
    def __init__(self, sequence_of_numbers):
        self._data = sequence_of_numbers

    @cached_property
    def stdev(self):
        return statistics.stdev(self._data)

    @cached_property
    def variance(self):
        return statistics.variance(self._data)
```

And then to test it out...

```
ds = DataSet(range(1, 20))
ds.stdev
5.627314338711377
ds.__dict__
{'_data': range(1, 20), 'stdev': 5.627314338711377}
ds.variance
31.666666666666668
ds.__dict__
{'_data': range(1, 20), 'stdev': 5.627314338711377, 'variance': 31.666666666666668}
```

Comment: Thanks @tyler. I guess this is one more excuse to move to 3.8!